# Strong inductive proof of division algorithm (quotient with remainder)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

The exercise goes like this:

> Prove the division theorem using strong induction. That is, prove that for $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ there always exists $q, r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a = qb + r$ and $r < b$. In particular, give a proof that does not use $P(n−1)$ to prove $P(n)$ when $b > 1$.

I have done a few proofs with strong induction before, but never with a predicate with multiple variables, so I'm unsure how to approach this.

One idea I had, was to use the following as my predicate:

$$P(a,b):= \exists r,q\in\mathbb{N}(a=b\cdot q+r)$$

and then use $\forall b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ .\forall i < a(P(i, b))$ as my first inductive hypothesis, and $\forall a \in \mathbb{N} .\forall i < b(P(a, i))$ as my second, proving them separately. But I'm not sure this is right, as I can't seem to prove it this way.

Am I even on the right track here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking, in my opinion.

Do induction on $a$.

For $a=0$, the statement is true: $0=b0+0$ and $0<b$.

Suppose $a>0$ and that the statement holds for all $c<a$.

If $a<b$, then $a=b0+a$ and $a<b$. If $a\ge b$, then $a-b<a$, so $a-b=bq+r$ with $r<b$; since $a=b(q+1)+r$, we're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by strong induction on $a$.

For $a=0$, it is trivial.

Now, consider an arbitrary $a\in\mathbb N$ and assume that each $a'<a$ can be written as $qb+r$, with $r<b$. Now, if $a<b$, you can write $a$ as $0\times b+a$. Otherwise, consider $a-b$. By the induction hypothesis, it can be written as $bq+r$, with $r<b$. But then $a=(q+1)b+r$.

Answer (score 2):

The *key idea* is that the set $S$ of integers of the form $\, a - n b\,$ is *closed under subtraction by* $\,b,\,$ hence we can repeatedly subtract $\,b\,$ from $\,a\,$ till we reach an element ("remainder") $\,r<b,\,$ i.e.

**Lemma** $\ $ If nonempty $\,S\subseteq \Bbb N\,$ is closed under  *nonnegative* subtraction by $\,b,\,$ i.e. $\,s\in S,\,s\ge b\,\Rightarrow\, s-b \in S,\,$ then $S$ contains a natural $< b$.

**Proof** $\ $ The $\rm\color{#c00}{least}$  $\,\ell\in S\,$ satisfies $\,\ell < b\,$ (else $\,\ell-b\in S\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ than $\,\ell)$.

**Remark** $ $ We used a form of induction known as the  *$\it\color{#c00}{least}$ number principle*, i.e. every nonempty subset $S$ of naturals has a least element (or, equivalently, $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered by magnitude). This can be viewed as a contrapositive form of strong induction (such *descent* arguments are often phrased in terms of a *least counterexample* (or *minimal criminal*), see [this Remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948742/242)).

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/889579/242) for a proof of the Division Algorithm by normal (not complete or strong) induction.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395067/242) for **uniqueness** of the remainder ([hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395053/why-are-naturals-modulus-equal-if-congruent-uniqueness-of-remainder#comment9920977_2395067) uniqueness of the quotient). $\ \ $